# How to groupby() and sortby() a Laravel collection?

Tags: sorting, laravel-5, methods, collections

This is the structure of my collection

```
  0 => array:13 [▼
    "id" => 173
    "campaign_id" => "STM1234"
    "product_id" => "STM1234"
    "group" => "24"
    "version" => "1"
    "created_at" => "2017-08-04 14:02:33"
    "updated_at" => "2017-08-04 14:02:33"
    "groups" => array:5 [▼
      "id" => 24
      "campaign_id" => "STM1234"
      "group_name" => "default"
      "updated_at" => null
```

I am trying to group and order this collection.

$groups = $products->groupBy('groups.group_name')->sortBy('groups.id');

The grouping works  however the ordering does not work

```
array:2 [▼
  "group2" => array:3 [▶]
  "default" => array:8 [▶]
]
```

Default has an id of zero so should be first what do I need to do to get the group with the id of 0 first on the list?